# Valgrind detect this as Possible Memory Leak

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, valgrind

Below is the extract of Code, in which i am getting some Possible memory loss in Valgrind Report.

```
681 int pbsc::PBSCAppMain( int argc, char **argv )
682 {
683     char pbscPath[255];
684     std::string configDir = "/../config/";
685     std::string pbscBinPath = getcwd(pbscPath,255);
686     std::string pbscConfigPath = pbscBinPath + configDir;
687
688
689
690     std::string localConfigFile = pbsc::GetFileNameFromDir(pbscConfigPath, PBSC_LOCAL_CONFIG_FILE);
691     if(false == localConfigFile.empty())
692     {
693         std::string localConfigFileWithPath = pbscConfigPath + localConfigFile;
694         ReadLocalConfiguration(localConfigFileWithPath);
695     }
696
697     std::string loggerConfigFile = pbsc::GetFileNameFromDir(pbscConfigPath, PBSC_LOGGER_CONFIG_FILE);
698     if(false == loggerConfigFile.empty())
699     {
700         std::string loggerConfigFileWithPath = pbscConfigPath + loggerConfigFile;
701         log4cxx::PropertyConfigurator::configureAndWatch(loggerConfigFileWithPath, 20000);
702     }
703
```

Below is the error what i am getting from Valgrind

```
==4594== 
==4594== 67 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 754 of 1,141
==4594==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==4594==    by 0x5812CA8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (new_allocator.h:104)
==4594==    by 0x581387A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:629)
==4594==    by 0x5813913: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:510)
==4594==    by 0x58139B7: std::string::append(std::string const&) (basic_string.tcc:332)
==4594==    by 0x455446: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:2369)
==4594==    by 0x45ED5F: pbsc::PBSCAppMain(int, char**) (PBSCApp.cpp:686)
==4594==    by 0x45EC9B: main (PBSCApp.cpp:677)
==4594==
```

My  Question is when control leave this function why still memory is associated to this function?
I am calling this function number of times that's why my program size keeps on growing.

Please suggest where exactly i am doing mistake.

Adding one more extract from Valgrind report that shows that even control return from the function but still memory taken freed.

```
==4594== 4,620 bytes in 110 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1,092 of 1,141
==4594==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==4594==    by 0x5812CA8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (new_allocator.h:104)
==4594==    by 0x581387A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:629)
==4594==    by 0x5813913: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:510)
==4594==    by 0x5087CA2: log4cxx::helpers::Transcoder::decode(std::string const&, std::string&) (transcoder.cpp:248)
==4594==    by 0x503FA1A: log4cxx::LogManager::getLogger(std::string const&) (logmanager.cpp:120)
==4594==    by 0x503A498: log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(std::string const&) (logger.cpp:490)
==4594==    by 0x4204D0: FIELD_UT::InitializeLogger(unsigned int, int) (FIELD_UT.cpp:19)
==4594==    by 0x415074: BeamM::FIELD_UT(unsigned int, int, int, int&) (Beam.cpp:62)
==4594==    by 0x4158E0: BeamM::OnUplinkLlcPdu(rgw::pbscpmc::PMC-PBSC-MetaMessage const&, int&) (BeamM.cpp:134)
==4594==    by 0x425551: PBSC_SYS::OnUplinkLlcPdu(rgw::pbscpmc::PMC_PBSC_MetaMessage const&) (PBSC_SYS.cpp:135)
==4594==    by 0x4136A2: PBSCAppMain::HandleMessage(unsigned short, char const*, int) (PBSCAppMain.cpp:28)
```

I can't post all the code but can elaborate the sequence, hope i will be able to make it....

1. As shown in Valgrind report, PBSCAppMain() after receiving something on socket call, PBSC_SYS::OnUplinkLlcPdu.
2. PBSC_SYS::OnUplinkLlcPdu calls  BeamM::OnUplinkLlcPdu.
3. BeamM::OnUplinkLlcPdu creates object for FIELD_UT.
4. from BeamM::OnUplinkLlcPdu, FIELD_UT::InitializeLogger is called to initialize its logger. Here is the exact code line for that.

   void BeamM::UpdateUT()
   {
       shared_ptr pUt = nullptr;
       pUt = AddUT(lli);
       pUt->InitializeLogger(lli);
   }

   void UT::InitializeLogger(unsigned int tlli, int beamId)
   {
       mLogger = log4cxx::Logger::getLogger("ut." + to_string(lli));
       LOG4CXX_DEBUG(mLogger, "UT Logger created");
   }

Now if i am not wrong, after initilizing Logger control will be back then why in that case also, valgring says...Possibly leak.

Thanks..

Comment: What happens if you comment out those function calls?

Comment: Looks like a false positive to me. Perhaps `pbsc::PBSCAppMain` invokes `exit`? Impossible to tell without a ***testcase***.

Comment: It looks like it's allocating memory to add the two strings, and then it doesn't get deallocated.

Comment: _"when control leave this function"_ When does that happen?

Comment: @Aereaux, That's it, what i am suspecting?

Comment: @Blindy which function? this whole function or anything specific in this function?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No Program has no exit, it stays in while 1, continously keeps on checking data on socket and also keep reading the files.. same file as stated in code.

Comment: @Verma: Well then if it stays in the loop forever (or, rather, until the process is forcibly terminated), then (within the context of the program) control _never_ leaves the function. So when did you expect these resources to be freed? Valgrind doesn't know either. This is a false positive; don't worry about it. (Note how it says "possibly lost", not "definitely lost".) Next time please show a ***testcase*** (as requested in the How To Ask guide) so that we can know this sort of detail immediately.

Comment: _"I can't post all the code"_ Nobody's asking you to. You're supposed to post a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No offence but I'm getting sick of repeating this several times a day; it should be obvious. :(

Answer (score 0):

> it stays in while 1, continously keeps on checking data on socket and also keep reading the files

Well if it stays in the loop forever (or, rather, until the process is forcibly terminated), then (within the context of the program) control *never* leaves the function.

So when did you expect these resources to be freed? Valgrind doesn't know either.

**This is a false positive; don't worry about it.**
*(Notice that it says "possibly lost", not "definitely lost".)*

Answer (score -1):

try changing

```
char pbscPath[255];
std::string configDir = "/../config/";
std::string pbscBinPath = getcwd(pbscPath,255);
std::string pbscConfigPath = pbscBinPath + configDir;
```

to

```
char pbscConfigPath[300];
getcwd(pbscConfigPath,255);
strcat(pbscConfigPath,"/../config/");
```

Old school but you don't have to worry about hidden class stuff, (and it's faster too).

Comment: Why is this marked down? This fixes the problem and gives a fast valid solution without memory errors.